# Struct - access to private fields

Tags: c#, struct

Why does it not generate an error?
If i try change **private field** of this struct in main program file - it generates an error, but not in struct implementation.

```
public struct MyStruct
{
    private int privateField;

    public int MyField
    {
        get { return privateField; }
        set { if (value >= 0) privateField = value; else value = 0 }
    }

    public void SomeMethod (MyStyruct s)
    {
        s.privateField = 10; // no error here.  
    }
}
```

Comment: interesting no error since you are calling it `MyStyruct` in `SomeMethod` ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Private members are restricted to the *class* or *struct* not the *object*.  In this case, even though `s` is a different object from `this`, it still works.

Comment: Great answer (will accept best answer after 7 minutes). Questoion 2 : should I use privateField to read data faster, or if I use MyField C# will optimize reading anyway?

Comment: Don't worry about that kind of micro-optimization. Use the property, unless you're creating a copy constructor. Especially since your setter has special logic.

Comment: I don't think you'll gain much performance by using privateField as opposed to MyField.  As far as I'm concerned it's a matter of style, unless if there are specific reasons for preferring one over the other (i.e. special logic in the getter or setter).

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, this has nothing to do with whether it's a struct or a class - or indeed whether it's a field or some other member.

Accessibility in C# is decided based on where the code is, not whether it's "this object" or another object.

Section section 3.5 of the C# specification for more details. For example, from 3.5.2:

> The *accessibility domain* of a member consists of the (possibly disjoint) sections of program text in which access to the member is permitted.

[...]

> If the declared accessibility of `M` is `private`, the accessibility domain of `M` is the program text of `T`.

Comment: Thank you, I'm reading alot of documentation, but my english isnt at advanced level, thats why i ask here.

Answer (score 4):

That behaviour is not specific to structs - it holds true of classes too.

`private` means the field is only accessible within the type. It is not meant to imply "only within the same *instance* of the type".

Given you are trying to access a private field from within the same type *even though it is a different instance of the same type*, `private` should allow access.

Answer (score 3):

`private` means that it can only be used in the scope of the `struct`.  It's an access modifier saying that the access level of this variable, function is `private` to the `struct` itself only.

You should use your property to change it outside of the struct, in `main` for example.

Your method `SomeMethod` is part of the struct, so you're allowed to change it's private members.

Although, the way you're accessing it, is a bit unusual.

Answer (score 2):

This is allowed because the passed in type is a MyStruct as well. This struct can access private members from a struct of the same type.

As others have pointed out, this behavior is the same for class types as well.

Answer (score 1):

Because `SomeMethod` is a method on the struct itself.  You wouldn't get an error on a class either- local members are allowed to modify private fields.

Answer (score 1):

The `private` modifier means that a member may only be accessed from within its type. It does not constrain access to from within its *instance*.